# Excel formula in PHP

Tags: php, excel

Can anyone tell me the math behind this MS Excel functions. I am writing code in php and I am unable to use
Excel to calculate these but I still need the same result.

```
CUMIPMT(rate,nper,pv,start_period,end_period,type) Returns the cumulative
interest paid on a loan between start_period and end_period.
```

My Excel Function -

```
=IF($C$33<0,CUMIPMT($C$36/12,$C$35,-$C$33,$C$34,$C$34+11,0),-CUMIPMT($C$36/12,$C$35,$C$33,$C$34,$C$34+11,0))
```

One more question - I used `(=E11-E12)` but it is not substracting, it adds both values, i cant understand why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean (=E11-E12) isn't subtracting? It doesn't work in Excel? It doesn't work in PHP? Please show details

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but you may want to check out the [PHPExcel Library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). Excel and PHP are different enough that you will either need to use a library like the one I linked to or write functions to do all of that math manually. In your case, it seems like handling excel files may be the easiest way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

One more question - I used (=E11-E12) but it is not substracting, it adds both values, i cant understand why?

Comment: It probably assumes that the '-' character means Columns E11 THROUGH E12 rather than E11 MINUS E12. I can't be too sure though since I don't really use excel.

Comment: Once you have coded your own function you can then compare and confirm your results with this Excel CUMIPMT calculator http://thinkanddone.co.uk/en-gb/excel_cumipmt_calculator.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question is still unanswered. I need a code logic behind CUMIPMT function in PHP.

Comment: @XiKam how did you manage to do this? I am working on the same thing, i need to calculate CUMIPMT in PHP without the use of Excel

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but I was working converting an Excel spreadsheet to objective-c today and needed an answer to this as well.  Here's the solution I ended up writing:

```
double cumipmt(double rate, int nper, double pv, int start_period, int end_period, BOOL type)
{
    double cumipmt = 0;
    double thePmt = pmt(rate, nper, pv, 0, type);
    double endValue = pv;

    if (type==0)
{
    for (int i=1; i<=end_period; i++)
    {
        double beginning = endValue;
        double interest = beginning * rate;
        endValue = beginning + interest + thePmt;

        if (i>=start_period)
        {
            cumipmt += interest;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i=1; i<end_period; i++)
    {
        double beginning = endValue + thePmt;
        double interest = beginning * rate;
        endValue = beginning + interest + thePmt;

        if (i>=start_period)
        {
            cumipmt += interest;
        }
    }
}

    return cumipmt;
}

double pvFactor(double rate, int nper)
{
    return (1 / fvFactor(rate, nper));
}

double fvFactor(double rate, int nper)
{
    return pow(1+rate,nper);
}

double annuityPvFactor(double rate, int nper, bool type)
{
    if (rate == 0) {
        return nper;
    }
    else {
        return (1 + rate * type) * (1 - pvFactor(rate, nper)) / rate;
    }

}

double pmt(double rate, int nper, double pv, double fv, bool type)
{
    return (-1 * (pv + fv + pvFactor(rate, nper))) / (annuityPvFactor(rate, nper, type));
}
```

I know this isn't in PHP, but it should be an easy task to convert.

Answer (score 0):

`IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )`

**condition** is the value that you want to test.

**value_if_true** is optional. It is the value that is returned if condition evaluates to TRUE.

**value_if_false** is optional. It is the value that is return if condition evaluates to FALSE.

So basically, it is saying this

```
if ($C$33 < 0) {
    // if the condition is TRUE
    return CUMIPMT($C$36 / 12, $C$35, -$C$33, $C$34, $C$34 + 11, 0);
} else {
    // if the condition is FALSE
    return -CUMIPMT($C$36 / 12, $C$35, $C$33, $C$34, $C$34 + 11, 0);
}
```

With regards to your **`(=E11-E12)`** problem. Try change it to this `=E11-E12`. If E12 is a negative number you gotta remember the minus sign will distribute.

**EDIT:**
With regards to your comment, I hope this link helps

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/515109-need-longhand-formulas-for-cumipmt-and-cumprinc-functions-in-excel.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question is still unanswered. I need a code logic behind CUMIPMT function in PHP.

I tried but not working -

P = principal amount (initial investment)
r = annual interest rate (as a decimal)
n = number of times the interest is compounded per year
t = number of years
A = amount after time t

A = P ( 1 + r/n ) nt, with P = 1500, r = 4.3/100 = 0.043,
n = 4 ( not 1/4 ), t = 6.